# Fiddler capturing XML-RPC

Tags: fiddler, xml-rpc

I was trying to capture xml-rpc calls to a localhost web site using Fiddler.  I have yet to see xml rpc traffic.

Specifically, I was using Windows Live Writer which relies on xml-rpc to update blog/story information with underlying metaweblog api.  I am able to connect Windows Live Writer to my code/local host but I want to see that traffic in fiddler.

Any ideas as to why I am not seeing it?

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic

Comment: Yes - thank you.  I have seen this documentation but I am not sure how/where to configure to capture xml rpc calls.

Comment: There's nothing special about them. As long as they are HTTP calls, Fiddler can intercept them - if the application respects the proxy settings. You may have to explicitly configure Fiddler as proxy in the application.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution for me was to use the machine name instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1
Once I started using the pc name I was able to view/capture traffic via xmlrpc.

Reference: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic